# Difference btw Gcloud TCP vs HTTP load balancer

Tags: http, tcp, load-balancing, gcloud

I have a jersey app running using embedded Jetty server, in GCE instances, fronted by load balancer. I load tested the setup with TCP load balancer, I'm able to get around 2400 QPS with under 20ms latency. But the same set up with HTTP load balancer I'm only able to get around < 1000 QPS with latency under 20ms.

When debugging I noticed there are a lot more opened file descriptors when using HTTP LB.

Following is my embedded jetty config, any ideas would be great! :)

```
    int httpPort = 8080;
    int maxThreads = 1024;
    int minThreads = 32;
    int idleTimeout = 500;
    QueuedThreadPool pool = new QueuedThreadPool(maxThreads, minThreads, idleTimeout, new java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue(6000));

    Server server = new Server(pool);
    ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server);
    httpConnector.setPort(httpPort);
    server.addConnector(httpConnector);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
```

Comment: Tell more about non HTTP load balancer. Is it some kind of LVS? If yes, then answer may be simple - LVS has better performance then HTTP LB.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this fixes the issue:

```
httpConnector.setIdleTimeout(100L);
```

Although I'm not sure why with gcloud TCP load balancer that's not an issue yet.